# University and Company logos alignment

Tags: titles

I'm pretty new in latex and I'm trying to make a title page, the problem is that the two logos in my title page are not aligned and my author is not centered:

[image: the problem]

```
\title{Stage Tek3}
\author{%
  jean\_c \\
  \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{img/Logos/septeo.jpg}\hspace*      {4.75cm}~%
     \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{img/Logos/Logo-Epitech.jpg}
  }
}
\date{April 2016 - July 2016}
```

can someone give me an explanation ?

Comment: Which class are you using `report` or `book` ?

Comment: If the width of the two logos plus the 4.75cm inter-logo space exceed the `\linewidth` of the page, then the two logos will appear on two, rather than a single line.  Try diminishing the 4.75cm gap and see if that fixes it.

Comment: DRi i use report and thanks steven I will try

Comment: I tried to remove the hspace but nothing happened

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you design something put flashy colors with :

```
\pagecolor{yellow}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
```

[image: My bad]

Comment: do you mind showing us the code as well?